# rails pagination - different per_page value page 1 from subsequent pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I have kinda blog/wiki application where I'd like the home page to include a welcome/landing message and the 5 most recent blog entries and pagination linking to older entries.

Is it possible to have, for example, 5 pages returned as page one of paginated search results and 15 for subsequent pages? I'm currently using will_paginate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `WillPaginate::Collection`, here is an example you can use for this :

```
def self.find_with_pagination(params = {})
  WillPaginate::Collection.create(params[:page].to_i < 1 ? 1 : params[:page], per_page_for_page(params[:page])) do |pager|
    # inject the result array into the paginated collection:
    pager.replace(find(:all, params.merge({:limit => pager.per_page, :offset => pager.offset)}))
    unless pager.total_entries
      # the pager didn't manage to guess the total count, do it manually
      pager.total_entries = self.count
    end
  end
end

def self.offset_for_page(page_number)
  page_number.to_i > 1 ? ((page_number.to_i - 2) * 15 + 5) : 0
end

def self.per_page_for_page(page_number)
  page_number.to_i > 1 ? 15 : 5
end
```

I hope it would help, here is a link for the doc : http://rdoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/master/WillPaginate/Collection

Comment: Thanks very much. Looks great but haven't time to check it out at the mo. Sure it'll be great but will get back.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like you have two distinct views that you're trying to combine into one: "Welcome" and "Archives".  It might be simpler just to split your one page into two:

- The "Welcome" page, which shows the welcome message, the latest X posts, and a link to "Older Posts".
- The "Archives" page, which has all the posts, `will_paginate`d as necessary.  Yes, the first five posts will show up here, too, but that's expected (and probably good) in an archive.

Just a different way to think about things - hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Xavier. Thanks for answer but in my case this approach won't work. I don't see them as distinct views really; this approach is fairly typical to blogs. Imagine the newest posts having larger representation on the front page say 1- 5 with 6 - 10 normal size. Then on page two I'll have 15 posts normal size in a similar total page size. Thanks again for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but perhaps by overriding the params[:per_page] on the subsequent pages will work.  Something like:

Since the controller is something like:

```
 @posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :include => [:posts], :conditions => ["post.user_id = ?", current_user.id], :order => "title,created_at"
```

the view perhaps could have something like this in it:

```
<%= params[:page] == 1 ? will_paginate @posts : will_paginate @posts, :per_page => 15 %>
```

Comment: Hi karudzo and thanks for your answer. Problem with that approach is posts 6 - 10 will never be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is a bit old, but I will give here my solution on Rails 4.2, because it is a bit different.

I need 10 results on first page, and 12 - on others.

item.rb

```
def self.find_with_pagination(params = {}, filters = {})
  WillPaginate::Collection.create(params[:page].to_i < 1 ? 1 : params[:page], per_page_for_page(params[:page])) do |pager|
    result = Item.all.limit(pager.per_page).offset(offset_for_page(params[:page])).where(filters)
    pager.replace result
    unless pager.total_entries
      # the pager didn't manage to guess the total count, do it manually
      pager.total_entries = self.count
    end
  end
end

def self.offset_for_page(page_number)
  page_number.to_i > 1 ? ((page_number.to_i - 2) * 12 + 10) : 0
end

def self.per_page_for_page(page_number)
  page_number.to_i > 1 ? 12 : 10
end
```

your_super_controller.rb

```
@items = Item.find_with_pagination(params, @filters)
```