# Pagination fails if some condition is checked in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

Want to show the records **satisfying some condition after retrieving it from the database** in Ruby on rails.

Problem is that :

currently I am showing the records using **will_paginate** gem without checking the condition after retrieving it from database.

and **if I check the condition** ; **some records fail to meet the condition will be eliminated**

**EDIT**

```
@result=MyRecord.paginate(:per_page => @perpage, :page => params[:page]).all
 #process records for conditions, if i eliminate records from @result that much records will be less for pagination
 @result #modified sent to view
```

So how to show the pagination for this.

Is their any alternative way to do the pagination after retrieving the records???

Comment: show us what you are doing at the moment, no code = limited help

Comment: what u dont understand about the question????

Comment: what conditions? what are you paginating? cant answer a question when theres nothing to go on, you need to post some code

Comment: I have posted u dont need to downvote...

Comment: well there was as poor question.. so what conditions are you passing before hand? do you want to show all results excluding conditions or do you want to only show the results that meet the condition?

Comment: results that meet conditions....

Comment: But conditions cannot be checked from query where clause ...It is massive calculation

Comment: and what is the code for the condition? cmon help us out here, is your condition wrapped in a method? or is it a scope?

Comment: calculation for distance of geolocation of records

Comment: method? scope?, can you post the code?

Comment: 'RADIUS=6371
  def distance_between(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    d_lat = toRad(lat2-lat1)
    d_lon = toRad(lon2-lon1)
    a = Math.sin(d_lat/2) * Math.sin(d_lat/2) + Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) *Math.sin(d_lon/2) * Math.sin(d_lon/2)
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
    d =RADIUS * c
    return d
  end'

Comment: yeah thats great but how are you calling the calculation? method? if so what is your method called

Comment: i am passing the lat lng of each successive points for checking distance

Comment: understand my problem or not????

Comment: You are incapable to understand the problem...That does not mean the question is poor .Remember this before down voting for any question...

Comment: yeah think you mean i am incapable of understanding the problem, the question was unclear, had no examples and did not show any research effort

Comment: There is much more to research in my question only to those who can understand it...  see the below answer he is one of them....

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, if you are getting less records which in turn not giving pagination then you can explicitly define your pagination for the number of records 
you want with the attribute `:per_page`. 
 So if you are getting only five records from database then define `:per_page => 5` in your
query to get the pagination.

This way you can go -

```
@result=MyRecord.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]).all
```

For varying results, WillPaginate::Collection will also help -

Check this post of SO - 
[rails pagination - different per_page value page 1 from subsequent pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829604/rails-pagination-different-per-page-value-page-1-from-subsequent-pages/4854443#4854443)

Comment: I am retriving per page 10 records .but @result is to be procesed to meet my condition . if some records fails to meet it .Total records will be reduced for that page....

Comment: I edited my post to give you the better solution that you want. Check my updated answer above.